# What is the best practice to start activity with intent extra in data binding?

Tags: android, data-binding

There are many ways to implement click events to start an activity with data binding. but all of them have cons. for example implement click listener method in the view model, make a presenter class or event handler class and even bind activity and use its methods. but what is the best practice to handle start activity with intent extras in data binding form?

Comment: @pskink I mean I want to this without break the mvvm pattern